# PROC TRANSPOSE: VAR 'all variables'?

Tags: sas, var, transpose, proc

I have this simple proc transpose:

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=VARS OUT=VARNAMES;
VAR VAR1;
RUN;
```

This works great at putting VAR1 in a variable and any obs in COL1.

However I have VAR1-VAR21. I may have more or less. is there a way to select all VARs without writing them all?

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: You could use: Var var1-var21; .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking data *null*'s advice I used

```
_ALL_
```

which specifies all variables that are currently defined datastep/procedure.

```
_CHARACTER_
```

and

```
_NUMERIC_
```

where also options which select only relevant variables.

Comment: It should be noted that the default VAR list for PROC TRANSPOSE is all numeric variables not use used in other statements; BY, COPY, or ID for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to use the "SAS Variable List" 
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/69852/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0wphcpsfgx6o7n1sjtqzizp1n39.htm